# Publish/Subscribe with RabbitMQ over HTTP

Tags: c#, http, rabbitmq, publish-subscribe, amqp

I have a requirement where messages should be published/subscribed over http with Advanced Message Queuing Protocol (AMQP - I am using RabbitMQ C# client), just like the sample chat application works with its json_rpc_channel plugin.

Please guide me through any valuable resource available to you.

Comment: What have you tried? RabbitMQ has a c# client library that exactly does what you want. Is there a reason the library doesn't fulfill your requirements?

Comment: I could not find a proper solution on the same.
curl --verbose -d body=hi -d "content-type=text/plain" http://guest:guest@localhost:80/test/test/foo. getting receiving error.

Comment: Then can u please guide me with an example command line for publishing a message to an exchange with the http url ?

Answer (score 2):

[Official .NET SDK](http://www.rabbitmq.com/dotnet.html)

[EasyNETQ - Easy to use wrappers](http://easynetq.com/)

If you can post specific requirement, pointers can be provided

Update:

[Publish](https://github.com/mikehadlow/EasyNetQ/wiki/Publish)

[Subscribe](https://github.com/mikehadlow/EasyNetQ/wiki/Subscribe)

Comment: What i want is a publish/subscribe application that will happen with amqp-http bridge with a njinx server proxy passes to amqp server.

Comment: Then can u please guide me with an example command line for publishing a message to an exchange with the http url ?

Comment: RabbitMQ provides web console and commandline tool (rabbitmqadmin). publish exchange=EXCH_NAME routing_key=all payload="Your payload"

Comment: Please ignore above comment. I was not able to edit. RabbitMQ provides web console and commandline tool (rabbitmqadmin). Command to publish => rabbitmqadmin publish exchange=EXCH_NAME routing_key=all payload="Your payload"

Comment: Thanks Lokeshwer for following up. 
I am unable to install rabbitmqadmin with the instructions they given.
This is where i am stucked now..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40654/discussion-between-lokeshwer-and-cslijo)

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.2.0\sbin>curl -i -u guest:guest -H "content-type:application/json" -XPUT -d"{""properties"":{},""routin
g_key"":""my key"",""payload"":""my 1body"",""payload_encoding"":""string""}" ht
tp://localhost:15672/api/exchanges/%2f/sampleTest/publish.

This is my command. is this correct to publish a message?

Comment: curl -i -u guest:guest -H "content-type:application/json" -XPOST http://localhost:15672/api/exchanges/%2f/TestExchange/publish -d'{"properties":{},"routing_key":"","payload":"Your payload","payload_encoding":"string"}'

Comment: This is the error i am getting..
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: MochiWeb/1.1 WebMachine/1.10.0 (never breaks eye contact)
Date: Thu, 07 Nov 2013 08:06:53 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 43

{"error":"bad_request","reason":"not_json"}